# Send FPDF File with WordPress wp_mail without saving PDF file

Tags: wordpress, pdf, fpdf

I am trying to create a PDF with the FPDF Library and send it via the WordPress wp_mail function to a specific email address. Important: I don't want to save the file first on my server.

There are many threads and websites, but none of the solutions worked for me.

At the moment I have the following code:

```
$email = 'test@mail.com';
$subject = 'Test attachment';
$body = 'This is the body text.';

$separator = md5(time());

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";

$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("test.pdf", "S");
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

wp_mail( $email, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachment );
```

I get an email without attachment. I have also tried:

```
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("test.pdf", "S");
$attachment = array( chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc)));

wp_mail( $email, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachment );
```

If I attach an image from my server, the file will be attached with the following code and is working fine:

```
$attachment = array( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/file/image.png' );

wp_mail( $email, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachment );
```

So my only problem is how to generate and attach the PDF file to the email.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I solved it by temporarily saving the file on the server and then deleting it after the email has been send. Works like a charm.

Here is the working code :

```
$email = 'test@mail.com';
$subject = 'Test attachment';
$body = 'This is the body text.';

$separator = md5(time());

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";

$filename = __DIR__ . "test.pdf"; // You specify the path for the file

$pdf->Output($filename, "F"); // "F" is for saving the file on the server

$attachment = array($filename);

wp_mail( $email, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachment );

unlink($filename); // Deletion of the created file.
```